# Passing function handler as input in a Simulink model

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have created a function handler in a .m file but I am working in a Simulink model and I want to pass this function handler as input to a subsystem in the model, how can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean function handle?

Comment: If you mean input as in a signal, then you can't -- signals are numeric.  If you mean input as a parameter (to a block mask for instance) then it works in exactly the same way as any other parameter (as long as the block has been written to accept a function handle).

Comment: @PhilGoddard I don't think it works this easily. I think you will need to use an 'Interpreted MATLAB Function' block.